# sql query to list rows with same column values and then delete a specific row

Tags: sql-server

I am new to sql and I'm using MS sql management server for examining a database. 
I need to write a sql query to  list rows with same column values and then delete a specific row. Eg:

```
+------+------+
|pid   |code  |
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|2     |A     |
+------+------+
|3     |A     |
+------+------+
|1     |B     |
+------+------+
|2     |B     |
+------+------+
```

For the above table, first I need to group rows with same 'pid'. Then within any group, if 'A' and 'B' are both present, I need to delete the rows with 'code' entry 'B'.
So from the above table I need to delete last 2 rows.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What if the `pid` only has `B`?

Comment: That row should not be deleted. The row has to be deleted only if that 'pid' has an 'A'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this;

```
select * from table1 where pid IN (
select pid from table1 group by pid 
having count(distinct code) > 1 and count(CASE WHEN code = 'A' THEN 1 END) > 0)
and code = 'B'
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c9a5d/4)

Comment: this works if 'code' is either 'A' or 'B'. But doesent work if there is an entry 'C' for a pid. Basically 'code' can have different kinds of letters, but I have to delete the row if there is 'A' AND 'B'. I should have been more precise.

Comment: You didn't provide any detail in the question about possibility of code is 'C'.

Comment: ya.. my bad.. I should have been more precise.

Comment: What if a pid has A,B,C. What records should be deleted ?

Comment: Record with 'B' has to be deleted. So, basically 'B' has to be deleted if and only if 'A' is present for that pid.

Comment: still doesn't work for condition when a pid has only 'C' and 'B' (i.e no 'A'). In this case, 'B' should not be deleted but this query deletes it.

Comment: THis works as expected.. THanks alot for your quick response.. Very much appreciated!!